# load params from database in joomla 2.5

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, module, joomla2.5

data params not load the database, I've tried several different structures for the MODULE but without success.

my is the following mod_xml

#

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension
type="module"
version="2.5"
client="site"
method="upgrade">
<name>mod_bruno</name>
<author>Joomla! Project</author>
<creationDate>July 2004</creationDate>
<copyright>Copyright (C) 2005 - 2013 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.        
</copyright>
<license>GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt</license>
<authorEmail>admin@joomla.org</authorEmail>
<authorUrl>www.joomla.org</authorUrl>
<version>2.5.0</version>
<description>Mod Bruno</description>
<files>
    <filename>mod_bruno.xml</filename>
    <filename>mod_bruno.php</filename>
</files>
<config>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="basic">
            <field name="bruno" type="text" />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</config>
</extension>
```

#

my is as follows mod_php

#

```
<?php
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

echo $params->get('bruno');
print_r($params);
die;

require( JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath( 'mod_bruno' ) );
```

#

always the result of my print_r in params is the following

```
JRegistry Object ( [data:protected] => stdClass Object ( ) )
```

and confirmed that this params updated in db as well visualized
    {"bruno":"teste"}

the value is in the database, but it does not display on screen

Obrigado

Comment: Why would you want to `print_r` a single parameter? Can you not simply stick to echoing it?

Comment: Seems like everything is configured properly. Do you have the ability to step through code using a debugger?

Comment: Why do you have the `die`?